# Running forever script from Google Cloud Platform App Engine startup script

Tags: node.js, bash, google-app-engine, mean-stack, forever

I have edited the startup-script variable for one of my instances running on the Google Cloud Platform App Engine.  I'd like it to call a forever script to make sure my node app is running.  So I added:

```
cd /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp
forever start --workingDir /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/ --sourceDir /opt
/bitnami/apps/myapp/ app.js
```

after the #!/bin/bash line (also tried without the cd as it's not really necessary based on my command).  But once the vm is started, running a **forever list** doesn't list my forever task as having ever started.  If I copy and paste that forever command into a gcloud terminal and run, the task shows up fine and my app starts no problem.

Am I not calling this correctly somehow within the bash script?

Comment: you can move to the directory where app.js is present and then try running  `forever start app.js`

Comment: @Ideluca - by chance did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @Brian See my answer

Answer (score 5):

[The simple answer is that GAE does this by default](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/migrating-to-split-health-checks). No need for `forever` or `PM2`. There are certain health checks that GAE does on the Docker container holding your app, and if they do not pass the instance is automatically restarted

If you want granular control over these checks (called [Legacy Health Checks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#legacy_health_checks)) you can add this to your `app.yaml` file:

```
health_check:
  enable_health_check: True
  check_interval_sec: 5
  timeout_sec: 4
  unhealthy_threshold: 2
  healthy_threshold: 2
```

There is also updated mechanisms (called [Updated Health Checks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#updated_health_checks)) that are still in beta, but can be used instead

Answer (score -1):

The proper way to start your nodejs app on appengine is to specify the `"scripts"` field in your `package.json`, as the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world)

Below is an example borrowed from this [sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/express/package.json)

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "test": "cd ..; npm run t -- appengine/analytics/test/*.test.js"
  },
```

If you however, are only interested in running a node script, and not interested in the features that come with Google app engine, then you may simply run it on a [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) instance.

Comment: This is not what I'm asking. I know how to start my app on Google Cloud Platform. What I'm trying to figure out is how to start when the instance restarts/starts.  Instead of manually.